# Equivalent of before :all in Test::Unit

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

If we use `setup` method, that method is executed before each test. I want to write a method, that will be executed once for a class.

In RSpec, there is a method called `before :all` which will allow me to do so. But I'm looking if there is equivalent method of `before :all` in Test::Unit

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729444/with-testunit-how-can-i-run-a-bit-of-code-before-all-tests-but-not-each-test

Comment: Thanks vigneshre! Actually, I'm looking if there is built-in method. If there is no such method, then I'll have to write my own code to handle this situation.

Comment: `before :all` is a code smell - it means your tests are no longer running in isolation because they're sharing a setup state.