# How to define common setup and teardown logic for all tests in ruby's Test::Unit::TestCase?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, installation, testunit, teardown

Assume there are potentially expensive operations to be performed in `setup` or `teardown` that are same for all tests and whose results doesn't get messed with during test runs. It seems not right to me to have them run before/after every single test.

So is there a preferred way to run setup/teardown code only before the first test is executed and only after the last test ran?

**Edit**: The particular case I'm working on should test some extensions to Net::FTP and thus establishes a FTP connection and sets up some remote objects for testing:

```
class TestFTPExtensions < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    # Setup connection
    @ftp = Net::FTP.new 'localhost', 'anonymous'
    @ftp.passive = true

    # Create remote test directory
    @ftp.mkdir 'dir'

    # Create remote test file
    path = File.join Dir.tmpdir, 'file'
    File.open path, 'w' do |f|
      @ftp.put f
    end
    File.delete path
  end

  def teardown
    @ftp.rmdir 'dir'
    @ftp.delete 'file'
    @ftp.close
  end

  # imagine some tests here that don't change/remove any remote objects

end
```

Comment: Depends on what that setup code does. If it adds things to a database, then a fixture/factory is the way to go - at least that's one example - you'd need to be more specific about what actions you're taking. It's also possible that you're tests are doing something outside their actual scope (for example, establishing a connection to an external API), and if it's a case similar to that, you should use mocks, stubs, etc. to simulate the stuff that's outside of what you're actually testing.

Comment: @normalocity I added information on my specific scenario. Still, I can imagine a lot of different scenarios where something like a common setup would come in even more handy. Regarding fixtures, factories, mocks and stubs: it would be helpful if you could come up with some links on these topics so I know what you're talking about ^^

Comment: I think this question has been asked before. You may be able to find it by browsing questions tagged "testunit".

Comment: factory_girl (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) will help you by creating objects in a database on the fly, related techniques will tell you about mocks and stubs (just search for "ruby mocks and stubs" and you'll get what you need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Andrew I found an answer to this [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/778701/380229).

However in the course of trying to find an answer I also noticed that in the 1.9.x branch the standard testing framework was switched to MiniTest. So actually I'm using that for testing right now. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6764734/380229) explains how to achieve the same with MiniTest.